# Working on Windows Server 2003, errors on 2008 ASP 0104 : 80004005 Operation not Allowed. NOT uploading file. Simple post

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, asp-classic

Hey guys we are experiencing a weird issue.

Classic ASP code is working on Windows 2003 Server.

But on Windows 2008 server when we try to do a simple Request.Form it gives ASP 0104 : 80004005 Operation not Allowed.

Not uploading any file in this request.

Tried to send only one value still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps we needed to do.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click on the website that has the issue.
3. In IIS Section click on ASP.
4. In Behavior section expand Limits Properties
5. Change "Maximum Requesting Entity Body Limit" from 200000 to 500000
6. click Apply on top right corner
7. Didn't need an IIS reset